# API Key configuration android

Tags: java, android, api, themoviedb-api

In my app I am going to use The Movies DB API to get most popular movies posters.

Kindly need your help with the below issue:

every time I try to run my app I get these errors

Error:(14, 77) error:  expected

Error:(14, 53) error: ';' expected

Error:(14, 45) error: malformed floating point literal

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


  android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.almaneakhaled.popularmoviesapp2"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'THE_MOVIE_DB', '967888xxxxxxxxx'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
 }
```

and here is where I get the error in the buildconfig.java:

at the top here there is a line saying "files under the build folder are generated and should not be edited"

```
 package com.almaneakhaled.popularmoviesapp2;

 public final class BuildConfig {
 public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
 public static final String APPLICATION_ID =      "com.almaneakhaled.popularmoviesapp2";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "";
 public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.0";
  // Fields from build type: debug
  public static final String THE_MOVIE_DB = 967888xxxxxxxxx;// this line is causing the issue
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use backslashes, change

```
it.buildConfigField 'String', 'THE_MOVIE_DB', '967888xxxxxxxxx'
```

to

```
it.buildConfigField 'String', 'THE_MOVIE_DB', "\"967888xxxxxxxxx\""
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Mehdi you are my hero